# How to read an excel file where columns are repeated in a single row and convert them into datatable

Tags: c#, .net, closedxml

I need to import an excel sheet and read the data and add this data to the database in ASP.NET Core MVC.

My table looks like this:

[image]

when I have the data in excel this format:

[image]

I'm able to read and add the data to database.

But I my Excel sheet is filled like this:

[image: this]

where the date is Day and Score and CutOf is in the single column header and these are repeating in a single row.

So how to read and convert them into a row basis for each guy and add them to the database?

```
var dt = new DataTable();

//Checking file content length and Extension must be .xlsx
if (file != null && file.ContentType.Length > 0 && System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
{
    //Create a Folder.
    string path = Path.Combine(hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
    
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    
    //Save the uploaded Excel file.
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        file.CopyTo(stream);
    }
    
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(filePath))
    {
        IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);
        bool FirstRow = true;

        //Range for reading the cells based on the last cell used.
        string readRange = "1:1";
        
        foreach (IXLRow row in worksheet.RowsUsed())
        {
            //If Reading the First Row (used) then add them as column name
            if (FirstRow)
            {
                //Checking the Last cellused for column generation in datatable
                readRange = string.Format("{0}:{1}", 1, row.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber);
                
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(readRange))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
                
                FirstRow = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Adding a Row in datatable
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int cellIndex = 0;
                
                //Updating the values of datatable
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(readRange))
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][cellIndex] = cell.Value.ToString();
                    cellIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        //If no data in Excel file
        if (FirstRow)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Empty Excel File!";
        }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with all the web technologies you tagged in your post? What code have you written to attempt to solve this problem? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, so you're expected to make an attempt at implementing this yourself. If you can't get it working, show what you've tried and explain how it's not working.

Comment: @mason Hey mason, did I anywhere mentioned saying give me the code?
you don't need to hurt somebody, just for the sake of you visited the question.
I was only asked how to do I iterate the columns which are repeating keep on,
As I can't have that many properties in a class object and assign them

Comment: You did not explicitly state you wanted someone to give you the code. But at the time you had not provided any code, so it's a logical conclusion that's where you were seeking. I'm not here to hurt you - I'm here to help. That means helping you understand how this site works best. We've got standards for how a question should be asked - standards we've developed over the past decade+ to help make your question clear and get answers to it. I see you've edited the code into your question now, thank you.

Comment: You've shown a snippet of what the Excel file looks like. Will it always have two days worth of scores in a single row? Or could have 1 to N, or 0 to N? Or 1 to 7? Or 0 to 7?

Comment: Thanks, mason, now onwards I'll maintain the standards while posting a question.
It will have 1 to N days along with the score in excel. 
my database table looks like

` ID | Name | Score | Outof `
In the given excel sheet, In a single column, I have score as well as the OutOf (Score/20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a dynamic number of columns, it's really just a matter of looping through the columns and grabbing the values. I recreated this on my machine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

namespace HelloDotNetCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scoreResults = new List<ScoreResult>();

            using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook("Scores.xlsx"))
            {
                var isHeaderRow = true;

                foreach (var row in workbook.Worksheet(1).RowsUsed())
                {
                    if (isHeaderRow)
                    {
                        isHeaderRow = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    var name = row.Cell(1).GetString();

                    // This goes through the Date, Score column pairs until the end is reached for that row
                    for (int i = 2; i <= row.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber; i+=2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(row.Cell(i).GetString());

                        var scoreResult = new ScoreResult
                        {
                            Name = name,
                            DateTaken = row.Cell(i).GetDateTime(),
                            Score = row.Cell(i + 1).GetValue<int>(),
                        };

                        scoreResults.Add(scoreResult);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var s in scoreResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {s.Name}, DateTaken: {s.DateTaken}, Score: {s.Score}");
            }
        }
    }

    class ScoreResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Notice how it grabs the scores, and stores them in a list for later use? That's far preferable to using a DataTable.

Comment: Thanks, Mason, 
Yes, Instead of dataTable, the List is much better as you suggested.
Just in case if anyone would like to know how to get the OutOf value from the header.
Iterating the first row, storing it in the List<string> and at for loop the index would be similar so getting the value and Score/17 value and splitting it and assign it to the OutOf.